# is there anything that we can add Eclipse VM arguments is some file rather than in run->configuration-> Arguments -> VM arguments:

Tags: java, junit, jvm-arguments

Actually in new java update JDK11: https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjira/java-11-and-jira-platform-upgrade-956160311.html

JVM parameter for locale compatibility we have to write
`"-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT"`.
Then only my jUnits work fine.

I can define it in Eclipse under `run->configuration->Arguments->VM`.
But I want to use them in centralized environment, like without Eclipse environment (in Team City).

**Can I achieve that so that my `jUnits` run well in centralized environment?**

Comment: Is your project `maven` based one? How do you build it in the `TeamCity`?

Comment: You can set something like System.setProperty("java.locale.providers", "COMPAT"); in setup() of your junit.

Comment: @Santosh No that is not recommended, java.locale.providers is read at java startup and even if your code might work for you now it can break at any point.